# Shell Script : Increment seconds to date printed in logs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I have date and time printed in log files as "14:09:49.922 UTC 12.08.2015"

To analyze the logs in few instances I have to grep for next X seconds from this date and time in the logs.

Note : Time Zone might vary.

I have used grep along with for loop to iterate the seconds or minutes or hours depending upon the give time.

The help I am looking for is the options in the  date command to increment seconds so that if I ad x seconds to the given time stamp, then date, month year, hour, minute and second should be updated accordingly.

Eg  : 23:59:59 UTC 31.12.2015" + 1 seond should return "00:00:00 UTC 01.01.2016".

Basically I am looking for options in date command instead of me manually checking if seconds crossed 59 then increment minute and so on.

How to achieve this in a shell script using date utility?

Comment: what have you tried so far ? It seems fairly simple to do. Try to delimit your capture using `:` and `.`. grep might also not be the best tool for this (it does not support capture group), maybe you could give `sed` a try

Comment: Question Edited/Updated.

Comment: First you can redirect your log input to another working file, Then you could make a cron task every X seconds which would read this working file, process all log lines in it, and remove content after process is over.

Answer (score 0):

Date command doesn't support "14:09:49.922 UTC 12.08.2015" format.

So I converted to "14:09:49.922 UTC 08/12/2015" and then used date utility as below

```
DATE="14:09:49 UTC 12.08.2015"  
NEXT_DATE=`echo $DATE | awk '{ split($3,a,"."); print $1" "$2" "a[2]"/"a[1]"/"a[3]}'`
TIME_ZONE=`echo $NEXT_DATE | awk '{print $2}'`  NEXT_DATE=`TZ="$TIME_ZONE" date +"%H:%M:%S %Z %m/%d/%Y" -d "$NEXT_DATE + 1 second"`
GREP_DATE=`echo $NEXT_DATE | awk '{ split($3,a,"/"); print $1" "$2" "a[2]"."a[1]"."a[3]}'`

grep $GREP_DATE logfile
```